# Checking what function was passed into a function

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a function as one of its arguments, but depending on the context that function could be one of several (they are all comparator functions for creating rules for the `sorted` method). Is there any way to check which function was passed into a function? What I'm thinking is some kind of conditional logic like this:

```
def mainFunction (x, y, helperFunction):
    if helperFunction == compareValues1():
         do stuff
    elif helperFunction == compareValues2():
         do other stuff
```

etc. Would this work? Would I need to pass in all of the arguments for the function when checking for its existence? is there a better way?

Comment: What if the user creates their own function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need to remove those parentheses:

```
def mainFunction (x, y, helperFunction):
    if helperFunction == compareValues1():  <-- this actually CALLS the function!
         do stuff
    elif helperFunction == compareValues2():
         do other stuff
```

Instead you would want

```
def mainFunction (x, y, helperFunction):
    if helperFunction is compareValues1:
         do stuff
    elif helperFunction is compareValues2:
         do other stuff
```

Comment: this as opposed to mine verifies that its actually really the function and not just the same name

Comment: note: if you are concerned about using the `is` keyword to compare function identity, read Raymond's answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942346/how-does-python-compare-functions

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def hello_world():
...    print "hi"
...
>>> def f2(f1):
...    print f1.__name__
...
>>> f2(hello_world)
hello_world
```

its important to note this only checks the name not the signature..

Answer (score 1):

```
helperFunction==compareValues1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are itself an object in python, So, when you pass a function to your function, a reference is copied to that parameter.. So, you can directly compare them to see if they are equal: -

```
def to_pass():
    pass

def func(passed_func):
    print passed_func == to_pass   # Prints True
    print passed_func is to_pass   # Prints True

foo = func    # Assign func reference to a different variable foo
bar = func()  # Assigns return value of func() to bar..

foo(to_pass)  # will call func(to_pass)

# So, you can just do: - 

print foo == func   # Prints True

# Or you can simply say: - 
print foo is func   # Prints True
```

So, when you pass `to_pass` to the function `func()`, a reference to `to_pass` is copied in the argument `passed_func`