# How do comparison operators < and > work with a function as an operand?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Ran into this problem (in Python 2.7.5) with a little typo:

```
def foo(): return 3
if foo > 8:
    launch_the_nukes()
```

Dang it, I accidentally exploded the Moon.

My understanding is that `E > F` is equivalent to `(E).__gt__(F)` and for well behaved classes (such as builtins) equivalent to `(F).__lt__(E)`.

If there's no `__lt__` or `__gt__` operators then I think Python uses `__cmp__`.

But, none of these methods work with `function` objects while the `<` and `>` operators *do* work. What goes on under the hood that makes this happen?

```
>>> foo > 9e9
True
>>> (foo).__gt__(9e9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__gt__'
>>> (9e9).__lt__(foo)
NotImplemented
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3.0+, that little typo would give you an obvious `TypeError: unorderable types: function() > int()`. In other words, it's a well-known problem that was solved, and you only have to worry about it if you use old versions of the language.

Comment: @digi_abhshk: Just do it the way the OP did in his code. It's guaranteed to return something consistent each time, but it's not guaranteed _what_ it returns. (In CPython 2.2-2.7, it will effectively compare the types of the objects by name.)

Comment: Note that if the left operand's `__gt__` doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`, Python tries the right operand's `__lt__`. If that doesn't work, it does weird crap you shouldn't rely on. (It doesn't try `__le__` or `__ge__`, mostly due to NumPy vectorized comparisons.)

Comment: Looks like (1).__lt__(foo) **returns** `NotImplemented`, rather than raising it. Of course `bool(NotImplemented) == True`

Comment: By the way: Surely you mean just `F.__lt__(E)`, not `F.__lt__(E) or F.__eq__(E)`; otherwise you'd be getting the equivalent of `E >= F`

Comment: @abarnert the inverse of `>` is `<=` correct?

Comment: @Cuadue: Yes, but this isn't about the inverse. Drop the abstraction and think about a simple case: `3 > 3` is not true, even though `3 <= 3` is, right? If you wanted to use the inverse here, you'd say `E < F iff not E >= F`, not `E < F iff F >= E`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does python compare functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942346/how-does-python-compare-functions)

Comment: @Cuadue: With many (but not all) operator special methods, returning `NotImplemented` (or, in C operator slots, returning a special value—IIRC 0, -1, -2, or 2 are all used in different places) means "go to the next fallback to implement this operator". This is documented for `__lt__` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But, none of these methods work with function objects while the < and > operators do work. What goes on under the hood that makes this happen?

In default of any other sensible comparison, CPython in the 2.x series compares based on type name. (This is [documented as an implementation detail](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons), although there are some interesting exceptions which can only be found [in the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l762).) In the 3.x series this will result in an exception.

The Python spec places some specific constraint on the behaviour in 2.x; comparison by type name is not the only permitted behaviour, and other implementations may do something else. It is not something to be relied on.

Comment: Very strange. It looks like `<type 'function'>` is actually *less than* `<type 'int'>`. So it looks like `type(foo) > type(8)` evaluates to `False`!

Comment: @Cuadue: Yes, the `function` and `int` types are both the same type, so they're compared by the `type.__lt__` slot-wrapper.

Comment: But 'function' is greater than 'int', which is what this anwser claims.

Comment: @abarnert It seems self inconsistent. `((type(1)).__gt__(type(foo))) == (1 > foo)` evaluates to `False`

Comment: @tdelaney: When compared as `type` instances, the `function` type is greater than the `int` type. But the name `"function"` is less than the name `"int"`, and when you compare a function to an int, it compares _based on type name_, not _based on type object_.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry I missed that subtelty, but `((type(1).__name__).__gt__(type(foo).__name__)) == (1 > foo)` is *still* `False`!

Comment: @Cuadue - okay, I gotta admit that's interesting

Comment: @Cuadue: Ah, that's a _different_ subtlety, which isn't documented, which I hoped wouldn't come up. The names that are being compared aren't actually the ones you see from their `__name__` attribute, and that's probably what's happening here. To be honest, I couldn't guarantee that without looking up the source. Which might be interesting here…

Comment: I think it's [`default_3way_compare`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l762) that implements the fallback code. And it's a bit surprising: objects that don't pass `PyNumber_Check` use the `tp_name` slot of their type object… but objects that _do_ are all treated as if they had the name `""` instead. (And if _both_ sides are numbers, they're compared by id of the type object. This also happens for two different types with the same name.)

Comment: I edited the answer to add links to the docs (which give the "by type name" rule) and the source (which shows that it's not absolutely followed); hopefully anyone interested in full details will read the comments. It might be worth writing up the whole comparison process (as implemented by CPython 2.7) from special attribute lookup to the same-named-type fallback in the fallback as pseudocode for those who don't want to trace through the source… but I'm too lazy to do that…

Comment: There's yet another twist in here. It goes through the same fallbacks you'd expect from the docs, just like two user-defined classes would (see [here](http://pastebin.com/xzMKt1af) for some code that shows the order), except that `int.__cmp__` exists and raises a `TypeError`—which would propagate as an exception for a user-defined (new-style) class, but for a builtin it still works as in Python 1.5, which means it falls back to the default-compare code instead.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for this research. I suspect this makes the answer, taken with your comments and edits the most complete source on this topic.

Comment: @Marcin Can you please undermine that statement with a  few examples on the Python command line?

Comment: @losauer I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 4):

> For future readers, I am posting this answer because [@wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) has placed a bounty on this question asserting [@Marcin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388016) is erroneous with the reasoning that `function < int` will evaluate to `False`, and *not* `True` as would be expected if lexicographically ordered by type names.
>
> The following answer should clarify some exceptions to the [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/) implementation; however, it is only relevant for Python `2.x`, since this comparison now throws an exception in Python `3.x`+.

## The Comparison Algorithm

Python's comparison algorithm is very intricate; when two types are incompatible for comparison using the type's built-in comparison function, it internally defaults to several different functions in an attempt to find a consistent ordering; the relevant one for this question is [`default_3way_compare(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/object.c#L767-L807).

The implementation for `default_3way_compare` performs the comparison (using lexicographical ordering) on the type's object names instead of their actual values (e.g. if types `a` and `b` are not compatible in `a < b`, it analogously performs `type(a).__name__ < type(b).__name__` internally in the C code).

*However*, there are a few exceptions that do not abide by this general rule:

- `None`: *Always* considered to be smaller (i.e. less) than any other value (excluding other `None`'s of course, as [they are are all the same instance](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html)).
- Numeric types (e.g. `int`, `float`, etc): Any type that returns a non-zero value from [`PyNumber_Check`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/abstract.c#L882-L888) (also documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Check)) will have their type's name resolved to the empty string `""` instead of their actual type name (e.g. "int", "float", etc). This entails that numeric types are ordered *before* any other type (excluding `NoneType`). This does not appear to apply to the `complex` type.

  For example, when comparing a numeric type with a function with the statement `3 < foo()`, the comparison internally resolves to a string comparison of `"" < "function"`, which is `True`, despite that the expected general-case resolution `"int" < "function"` is actually `False` because of lexicographical ordering. This additional behavior is what prompted the aforementioned bounty, as it defies the expected lexicographical ordering of type names.

See the following REPL output for some interesting behavior:

```
>>> sorted([3, None, foo, len, list, 3.5, 1.5])
[None, 1.5, 3, 3.5, <built-in function len>, <function foo at 0x7f07578782d0>, <type 'list'>]
```

More example (in Python 2.7.17)

```py
from pprint import pprint
def foo(): return 3
class Bar(float): pass
bar = Bar(1.5)
pprint(map(
    lambda x: (x, type(x).__name__), 
    sorted(
        [3, None, foo, len, list, -0.5, 0.5, True, False, bar]
    )
))
```

output:

```
[(None, 'NoneType'),
 (-0.5, 'float'),
 (False, 'bool'),
 (0.5, 'float'),
 (True, 'bool'),
 (1.5, 'Bar'),
 (3, 'int'),
 (<built-in function len>, 'builtin_function_or_method'),
 (<function foo at 0x10c692e50>, 'function'),
 (<type 'list'>, 'type')]
```

## Additional Insight

Python's comparison algorithm is implemented within [`Object/object.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/object.c)'s source code and invokes [`do_cmp(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/object.c#L817-L849) for two objects being compared. Each `PyObject` instance has a reference to its built-in [`PyTypeObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/type.html#c.PyTypeObject) type through `py_object->ob_type`. `PyTypeObject` "instances" are able to specify a `tp_compare` comparison function that evaluates ordering for two objects of the same given `PyTypeObject`; for example, `int`'s comparison function is registered [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/intobject.c#L1419) and implemented [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/intobject.c#L449-L455). However, this comparison system does *not* support defining additional behavior between various incompatible types.

Python bridges this gap by implementing its own comparison algorithm for incompatible object types, implemented at [`do_cmp(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/object.c#L836-L848). There are three different attempts to compare types instead of using the object's `tp_compare` implementation: [`try_rich_to_3way_compare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/object.c#L674-L698), [`try_3way_compare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/object.c#L707-L759), and finally [`default_3way_compare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Objects/object.c#L767-L807) (the implementation where we see this interesting behavior in this question).

Comment: @wim You should give this answer the bounty. FYI the information about exceptions is treated briefly in my answer with a link to the source.

Comment: The motivation for this design was that numbers be grouped together and ordered when sorting heterogeneous lists. Then an exception came for complex type, and the original intention was no longer convincing. Details on the historical context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384078/why-is-0-true-in-python-2).

Answer (score -2):

Note: this only works in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, it gives:

> TypeError: '(comparison operator)' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'.

In Python 2.x, functions are more than infinitely large.  For example, in [Python 2.7.16 (repl.it)](https://repl.it/languages/python), type this:

```
> def func():
...    return 0
...
> print(func)
<function func at 0xLOCATION>
> int(func)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'
> id(func)
IDNUMBER
> x=id(func)
> func<x
False
> func==x
False
> inf=float("inf")
> func<inf
False
```

This shows that 'func' is greater than positive infinity in Python 2.x.  Try this in [Python 3.8.2 (repl.it)](https://repl.it/languages/python3):

```
> def func():
...    return 0
...
> func<10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'
```

This shows that comparing with a function as an operand is only supported in Python 2.x, and that when comparing a function in Python 2.x, it is greater than Python's infinity.