# Why does 0 < () evaluate to True in Python?

Tags: python, collections, comparison, boolean, logic

I inadvertently typed `time.clock<()` with the Python 2.7 interpreter response being: `True`. The following code exemplifies the behavior:

```
>>> repr(time.clock)
'<built-in function clock>'
>>> time.clock<()
True
```

*Moreover:*

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint < ()
True

>>> map(lambda _:0<_,((),[],{}))
[True, True, True]
```

*In contrast:*

```
>>> 1<set(())
TypeError: can only compare to a set
```

Question: *Besides why, is there a practical meaning or purpose of an empty `list`, `tuple` or `dict` evaluating as if were greater than any number?*

---

***Update***:

- *Viktor* pointed out that memory-addresses are compared by default:

  `>>> map(lambda _:(id(0),'<',id(_)),((),[],{}, set([])))`

  `[(31185488L, '<', 30769224L), (31185488L, '<', 277144584L), (31185488L, '<',
  279477880L), (31185488L, '<', 278789256L)]`

Despite the seeming order, **this is incorrect**.

---

- *Martijn Pieters* points out that:

> Without an explicit comparison operator defined, Python 2 compares by
>   Numbers and Type-names, with numbers having the lowest precedence.

This does not hint at what exact internal methods are being invoked. See also this helpful but [inconclusive SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387938/how-do-python-comparison-operators-and-work-with-a-function-name-as-an-opera?lq=1):

In an IPython 2.7.5 REPL

```
>>> type(type(()).__name__)
Out[15]: str

>>> type(()) < 10
Out[8]: False
>>> 10 < type(())
Out[11]: True
#as described
>>> type(()) < type(())
Out[9]: False
>>> type(()) == type(())
Out[10]: True

However:
>>> 'somestr' .__le__(10)
Out[20]: NotImplemented
>>> 'somestr' .__lt__(10)
Out[21]: NotImplemented

>>> int.__gt__
Out[25]: <method-wrapper '__gt__' of type object at 0x1E221000>
>>> int.__lt__
Out[26]: <method-wrapper '__lt__' of type object at 0x1E221000>

>>> int.__lt__(None)
Out[27]: NotImplemented
    #.....type(...), dir(...), type, dir......
#An 'int' instance does not have an < operator defined
>>> 0 .__lt__
Out[28]: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__lt__'

#int is actually a subclass of bool
>>>int.__subclasses__()
Out: [bool]
#str as the fallback type for default comparisons
>>> type(''.__subclasshook__)
Out[72]: builtin_function_or_method
>>> dir(''.__subclasshook__)
Out[73]: 
['__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__cmp__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__name__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__self__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
#IPython is subclassing 'str' 
>>> str.__subclasses__()
Out[84]: [IPython.utils.text.LSString]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Python comparison operators < and > work with a function name as an operand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387938/how-do-python-comparison-operators-and-work-with-a-function-name-as-an-opera)

Comment: Note that in python3 all these comparisons raise `TypeError`: `>>> 0 < ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < tuple()`

Comment: Viktor's answer was incorrect.

Comment: @Bakuriu I too was under the impression that it should be so. Thanks for reassuring that.

Comment: This is one of the awkward things that in python3 were fixed with a backward incompatible change(and with good reasons). If you don't have compelling reasons to stay with python2(e.g. cannot upgrade the box, or missing dependencies) I'd strongly suggest to start using python3(but *do* read the various "what's new")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2, when comparing *different* types, python sorts numeric types before everything else, and between the rest sorts types *by type name*.

Thus, integers sort before tuples, but instances of class `Foo` will sort *after* instances of class `Bar`.

Python 3 does away with this madness; comparing different types results in a TypeError instead:

```
>>> 10 < ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < tuple()
```

The Python `set()` type has overloaded the `>` operator by implementing the [`__gt__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__) or 'greater then' magic method; it is called for the `1 < set()` expression because the `int` type has no `__lt__`, lower-then and Python tests the inverse in that case; after all, `x < y` is true if `y > x` is true.

The `set.__gt__()` hook raises a `TypeError` when the other operand is not a `set`:

```
>>> 1 .__lt__(set())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__lt__'
>>> set().__gt__(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only compare to a set
```

The overloaded `>` (greater then) operator for sets is used to test if the left-hand operand is a [proper superset of the right-hand operand](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issuperset). (Technically, `set` objects implement the C-API [`PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare) function, not the `__gt__` hook directly, but the `__gt__` hook translates to a `tp_richcompare` call in that case automatically).

When an overloaded comparison method (one of [`.__lt__()`, `.__le__()`, `.__eq__()`, `. __ne__()`, `. __gt__()`, `. __ge__()`, or `. __cmp__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)) returns the `NotImplemented` singleton object this signals that the comparison is not supported and Python falls back to the default behaviour. This default behaviour, as already stated in [How do Python comparison operators < and > work with a function name as an operand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18387938) differs between Python 2 and 3.

For Python 3, a comparison hook returning `NotImplemented` causes Python to raise `TypeError`:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     def __lt__(self, other): return NotImplemented
... 
>>> Foo() < Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: Foo() < Foo()
```

Python 2 is more stubborn and when `NotImplemented` is returned or no hooks have been implemented, the C code ends up in the [`default_3way_compare()` C function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d5c5ac33b9a1/Objects/object.c#l763), which:

- Orders by memory addresses when the types of both objects are the same (line 768-776)
- Orders `None` before anything (line 780-783)
- Orders numbers before other types (`PyNumber_Check` tests set type name to empty, lines 786-793)
- Orders by typename (`v->ob_type->tp_name` and `w->ob_type->tp_name` in lines 786-793)
- If the type *names* are the same, orders by memory address of the type objects (lines 800 and 801).

Comment: Also the `set` example fails because `<` is *not* the less than operators for sets, it's treated as the "is sub set" operator, which obviously doesn't make sense with non-set operands. (I believe the python docs somewhere explicitly state that the language does not define the semantics of `<`, `>` etc., hence this difference)

Comment: @Bakuriu: I am explaining what `lt` stands for, not what the operator now is used for in sets.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I still cannot place the comparison steps though. Please help me out, as the long-standing Pythionist that you are and I will gladly accept your answer. See also my update.

Comment: @LoSauer: Boy, you dug yourself a hole into wonderland, didn't you? I'll see what I can do when I have some time.