# PyLint W0143 warning: Comparing against a callable

Tags: python, pylint

I trying to test pylint with default settings and (see python code below) get a warning:

```
>pylint pylint_test_01.py
>pylint_test_01.py:24:7: W0143: Comparing against a callable, did you omit the parenthesis? (comparison-with-callable)
```

How can I get rid of this pylint warning without breaking this algorithm and without disable pylint checks (i.e. with default settings)?
General principle of enumerating functions from list should remain.

```
'''Test pylint with default settings warnings'''
from random import randint
def sortaray_builtin(arr):
    '''This is built in Python sort function'''
    return sorted(arr.copy())
def sortaray_bubble(arr):
    '''Bubble sorting algorithm -- is a simplest of sorting algorithms. Perfomance: O(N**2)'''
    brr = arr.copy()
    for i, _ in enumerate(brr[:-1]):
        for j in range(i, len(brr)):
            if brr[i] > brr[j]:
                brr[i], brr[j] = brr[j], brr[i]
    return brr

SFUNCTIONS = [
    sortaray_builtin,
    sortaray_bubble
]

ARSIZE = 20
ARRY = [randint(0, ARSIZE) for i in range(ARSIZE)]

for SrtFunc in SFUNCTIONS:
    # Line below cause an W0143: Comparing against a callable, did you omit the parenthesis? (comparison-with-callable)
    if SrtFunc == sortaray_builtin:
        print("Builtin: ", end='', flush=True)
    else:
        print("Bubble : ", end='', flush=True)
    print(SrtFunc(ARRY))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can disable checks for some places.

```
if SrtFunc == sortaray_builtin:  # pylint: disable=W0143
```

More info
https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html

**Option 2**

You can get the name of a function with `__name__` attribute.

```
SrtFunc.__name__ == builtin_sort.__name__
```

**Option 3**

Same as the second method, but with `.__doc__`

```
SrtFunc.__doc__ == builtin_sort.__doc__
```

**Option 4**

You can wrap your functions in objects, e.g. in dict, or create a special class.

```
class Sorter():
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.sort = func
builtin = Sorter(sortaray_builtin)
bubble = Sorter(sortaray_bubble)
SFUNCTIONS = [ builtin, bubble ]
builtin.sort()
```

Comment: I know how to disable checks. But sense is to past pylint checks with default settings.

Comment: @An0ther0ne I added other methods

Answer (score 6):

You could use `is` for function comparisons:

```py
if SrtFunc is sortaray_builtin:
```

This is also what happens under the hood when you use `==` to compare two functions, as there is no way to otherwise determine if two functions are equivalent.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942346/how-does-python-compare-functions) for more details on how comparisons on functions work.

Comment: I'm not compare equivalence of two functions, I want to check if some function in list is exactly the same as I describe in comparison. 
In example at your link there two actually function definition, they looks like the same, but not. In addition, after 8 years in the version of Python 3x, this does not work as described. For example: fun1=lambda :x; fun2=lambda :x; fun1 == fun2 ==> False

Comment: @An0ther0ne I know you're not, I'm merely stating that it's impossible to check whether functions are equivalent. In this example you've given, you're still defining two *different* lambda functions, although they have the same function body. Using `==` to compare functions is exactly the same as using `is` which checks whether the values are the same object, which is why you get `False` here.

Comment: Specifics of using `is` keyword are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3258748/12446146)

Comment: @An0ther0ne I understand what `is` does, and I know that it's different from `==`. What I'm saying is, in the case of comparing functions, `==` works the same as `is`. This is because there is no way to determine equivalence of function, so no `__eq__` is defined for functions, thus `==` falls back to identity comparison, which is what `is` does. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons).