# Python newbie: why does comparing two sort list return false

Tags: python

```
A = [1,2,4,3]
B = [4,3,2,1]

C=A.sort == B.sort

print(C)
```

output shows false, why? A and B should both be sorted in place to be [1,2,3,4]

Comment: You're comparing two functions. If you want to call them, add parentheses. Even if you do call them, `.sort` is inplace. You probably meant `sorted(A) == sorted(B)`.

Comment: Because you didn't read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - What @ggorlen said

What you have currently does not do what you think it does. I think what you're looking for is this:

```
A = [1,2,4,3]
B = [4,3,2,1]

print(sorted(A) == sorted(B))  # True
```

The code you have is just comparing two method objects `A.sort` and `B.sort`. You can read more about function comparison [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942346/how-does-python-compare-functions).

Answer (score 1):

`A.sort` is  a function definition and is attached to the unique object `A` and `B` which is why they do not match.

If you ran

```py
print(A.sort == A.sort)
```

You would get `True`.

You need to call the function if you want to sort each list:

```py
A = [1, 2, 4, 3]
B = [4, 3, 2, 1]
A.sort()
B.sort()

C = A == B
print(C)
```

Which will give `True` as expected. *Note that `A` and `B` will be sorted in-place meaning that the order of values in `A` and `B` will have changed.

If you wanted to compare sorted lists without modifying `A` or `B` you should do something like:

```py
A = [1, 2, 4, 3]
B = [4, 3, 2, 1]

C = sorted(A) == sorted(B)
print(C)
```

[sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) will return a new sorted copy so neither `A` or `B` will be affected.

Assuming you're trying to find ways to see if 2 lists contain the same elements regardless of order and don't really need the sorted versions see [How to efficiently compare two unordered lists (not sets) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7828867/15497888).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sorted(A)` and `sorted(B)` instead of `A.sort`.

`A.sort` is actually a reference to the sort function on lists.

`A.sort()` returns None: it sorts A in place but does not return the list.

`sorted(A)` does not change `A`, it returns a new, sorted list.

```py
A = [1, 2, 4, 3]
B = [4, 3, 2, 1]

C = sorted(A) == sorted(B)
print(C)
```